# Disable panel horizontal scroll when text is entered in textfield

Tags: extjs, panel, extjs6-classic

I want to disable horizontal scroll of panel when someone enter text in text field.
**First problem:**
Currently problem is when you enter text in any textfield and press right arrow key from keyboard (keyCode = 39) then panel horizontal also move in right direction. I want to diable that when text is entered in textfield.
**second Problem**
Horizontal scroll moves with key only when click on that panel.

Fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mjd

```
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    scrollable: 'horizontal',
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'hbox',
    baseCls: '',
    containerScroll: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }],
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        margin: '0 0 0 9'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }],
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        margin: '0 0 0 9'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }],
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        margin: '0 0 0 9'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }],
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        margin: '0 0 0 9'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }],
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        margin: '0 0 0 9'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }],
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        margin: '0 0 0 9'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }],
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        margin: '0 0 0 9'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: I am testing this 6.0.0 classic. It is not happening for me.

Comment: No it happens in all versions greater than 5

Comment: As i noticed when entering in textfield and then right arrow panel is not scrolling horizontally and it happening only when mouse is clicked on panel.

Comment: Yes when focus is set on that panel. i want to stop that

Comment: or is this possible to stop horizontal move when key is press

Comment: Yes, I am try to preparing a code for that only. Key disabling event on panel. Good ques

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130665/discussion-between-ajay-thakur-and-udid).

Comment: @UDID any updates regarding code?

Comment: Sorry, but i can't reproduce your error, can you explain me what exactly I need to do to reproduce it? i'm trying your fiddle but all seems to go well

Comment: when you enter text in textfield and press right arrow key from keyboard. then you notice horizontal scroll of panel also move to right. i want to disable horizontal scroll on key when text is entered.

Comment: @Mr.Bruno any updates regarding this post.

Comment: @AjayThakur Not able to reproduce your 1st issue. Regarding your 2nd issue if you click on panel then press -> key then its obvious behavior that scroll will happen, so you cant avoid unless you write code after focusing on text-field.