# How to Drag Name1 To Name 6 panel

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs6, extjs6-classic

How to drag a panel item from another panel?

For example: I want to drag Name1 To Name 6 panel. When I tried by pressing shift+mousescrollkey, then it loose dragging item.

Thanks in advance :)

Fiddle:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hgf&view/editor

```
    Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('myColumn', {
            extend: 'Ext.view.View',
            xtype: 'mycolumn',

            padding: 5,
            margin: 5,
            style: 'background-color: #f2f2f2;',

            itemSelector: 'div.nameselector',
            tpl: ['<tpl for=".">', '<div class="nameselector<tpl if="isTemp"> temp</tpl>">', '{name}', '</div>', '</tpl>'],

            listeners: {
                render: function(me) {
                    var tempRec = null;

                    // Create drag zone
                    this.dragZone = new Ext.dd.DragZone(me.getEl(), {
                        // On receipt of a mousedown event, see if it is within a DataView node.
                        // Return a drag data object if so.
                        getDragData: function(e) {
                            // Use the DataView's own itemSelector (a mandatory property) to
                            // test if the mousedown is within one of the DataView's nodes.
                            var sourceEl = e.getTarget(me.itemSelector, 10);
                            // If the mousedown is within a DataView node, clone the node to produce
                            // a ddel element for use by the drag proxy. Also add application data
                            // to the returned data object.
                            if (sourceEl) {
                                d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                                d.id = Ext.id();
                                return {
                                    ddel: d,
                                    sourceEl: sourceEl,
                                    sourceZone: me,
                                    sourceStore: me.store,
                                    repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY(),
                                    draggedRecord: me.getRecord(sourceEl)
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        getRepairXY: function() {
                            return this.dragData.repairXY;
                        }
                    });

                    this.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(me.getEl(), {
                        // Helper method to return correct class string if drop
                        // is permitted or not.
                        getAllowed: function(allowed) {
                            var proto = Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype;
                            return allowed ? proto.dropAllowed : proto.dropNotAllowed;
                        },

                        notifyOver: function(source) {
                            return this.getAllowed(source !== me.dragZone);
                        },

                        // Called when dragged element is over a drop zone.
                        // If allowed, make a copy of the dragged record to
                        // display in the zone (temporarily) by adding the record
                        // to the column store.
                        notifyEnter: function(source, e, data) {
                            var allowed = source !== me.dragZone;
                            if (allowed) {
                                tempRec = data.draggedRecord.clone();
                                // Set record field 'isTemp' to true which will cause the dataview
                                // template to use the 'temp' style defined in app.css
                                tempRec.set('isTemp', true);
                                me.getStore().add(tempRec);
                            }
                            return this.getAllowed(allowed);
                        },

                        // Called when the dragged element leaves a container. Remove
                        // the temporary record from the column store, removing the placeholder.
                        notifyOut: function(source, e, data) {
                            if (tempRec) {
                                me.getStore().remove(tempRec);
                            }
                        },

                        // When a dragged source is over a container, 
                        // set the appropriate drop style for the dragged element.
                        onContainerOver: function(source, e, data) {
                            return this.getAllowed(source === me.dragZone);
                        },

                        // When the element is dropped on a column, check to see
                        // if we are dropping on the same column or not. If not,
                        // then remove record from source column, add record to 
                        // drop column.
                        onContainerDrop: function(source, e, data) {
                            var overSame = source == me.dragZone,
                                dragData = source.dragData;

                            if (overSame) {
                                // Do not allow drop over same zone
                                // Return false to do a repair.
                                return false;
                            }

                            var rec = dragData.draggedRecord;
                            dragData.sourceStore.remove(rec);
                            me.getStore().add(rec);

                            // Clear temporary record
                            tempRec = null;

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            plugins: 'viewport',
            scrollable: 'horizontal',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            defaults: {
                'width': 300
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'mycolumn',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Name 1'
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'mycolumn',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Name 2'
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'mycolumn',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Name 3'
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'mycolumn',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Name 4'
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'mycolumn',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Name 5'
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'mycolumn',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Name 6'
                    }]
                }
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: can autoscroll be a solution??

Comment: @Mr.Bruno autoScoll:true also not working

Comment: I've tried so many solutions that i used and no one want to scroll your panel automatically, +1 for me, we'll wait for other slutions

Comment: @Mr.Bruno can you help me in this question also..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157515/disable-panel-horizontal-scroll-when-text-is-entered-in-textfield

Comment: @AjayThakur are you limited to the version 6.0.2 ?

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in ExtJS version `6.0.2` the scroll config on the dragZone doesn't work. Neither does `panel.scrollBy()` by which you can scroll that panel.

I think that you will have to update your framework.

When you update to `6.2.0.589` the scrollBy function will start working. You could add mouse event to each column and when you are over that, scroll the main panel.

```
containermouseover: function (me) {
    var panel = Ext.first('#myMainPanel');
    panel.scrollBy(me.getX() - panel.getWidth() / 4, 0, true);
},
```

When you update to `6.2.0.981` the [`scroll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.dd.DragZone.html#property-scroll) config in the dragZone will start working.

```
this.dragZone = new Ext.dd.DragZone(me.getEl(), {
    ...
    // this doesn't work in 6.0.2 but works in 6.2.0.981
     scroll: true
});
```

My fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qse

But now when you hold an item and you scroll into the column and it's dropZone which was not in the view before, the column is not registered as a dropZone and you can't drop the item. The events notifyOver are not called.

And I am getting the same results when I experiment with http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/classic/dd/dragdropzones.html

I assume that this is another ExtJS bug.

*In general I don't think it's good UX design when you have to scroll while using drag and drop.*

Comment: Actually i am creating kanban in Extjs in which there is horizontal scroll. When task lists are large then we need scroll to view that lists. There are lots of tasks and we can drag task of any list to another lists which was not in view.

Comment: @AjayThakur I tried to google why the dropzone is not registered after the scroll and I found some info that there might be problems when the zones  are used in Ext.view.* and shares the same element. It might be worth to rewrite it to container which has the zone + view or something like that.